# 2D array scanner validation

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, java.util.scanner

Anyone able to steer me in the right direction. I am building a simple mark program where I get input from Scanner and insert it into my 2D array. I want to validate my input so that it isn't below 0 or above 100 but if I have the incorrect number I don't want the array to move to next position.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);//naming the scanner
    String [] student = {"Mark","Jen","Gaby","John","Michael","James"};
    String [] subject = {"Digital electronics","Analogue electronics","Maths","Networks","Telecommunications",
            "Computer applications","Software developemnt","Workshop"};
    String [] printSub = {"Digit","Analo","Maths","Netwo","Telec","Appli","Softw","Works"};
    int maxRow = 6;//setting max row amount int
    int maxCol = 8;//set max column amount int
    int [][] mark = new int [maxRow][maxCol];//declaring the int array and setting the row & column max.
    int i = 0, j = 0;//declaring i and j for use in the for loops 
    int maxMark = 0;//declaring for use in if statement to find highest mark
    int minMark =100;//Declaring for use in if statement to find lowest mark

    for(i = 0; i < maxRow; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < maxCol; j++)
        {
            System.out.print("Please enter "+student[i]+" mark for "+subject[j]+" and press return :");
            mark[i][j]= input.nextInt();
        }
    }

    for(i=0; i < maxRow; i++)
    {           
        for(j=0; j < maxCol; j++)
        {
            if (i == 0 && j == 0)
            {
                System.out.print("Student  \t");
                for(int sub = 0; sub < 8; sub++)
                {
                    System.out.print(printSub [sub]+"\t");
                }
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println();
            }
            if(i < maxRow && j == 0)
            {
                System.out.print(student[i]+"\t \t  ");
            }

            System.out.print(mark [i][j]+"\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

I am not looking for the answer i am looking for more of a nudge in the direction where I may be able to figure out the answer myself.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nudge : You do not directly insert number into array, you insert it into some temporary variable, checks it and then decide if you save it or you ask again (while cycle needed)

---

Spoiler 1 : Here is complete solution, if you want to do it yourself, do not look there :) :

```
    for (i = 0; i < maxRow; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < maxCol; j++) {
            System.out.print("Please enter ");
            int number = input.nextInt();
            boolean isItOk = false;
            while (isItOk == false) {
                if (number < 0 || number > 100) {
                    System.out.println("You shall not insert a value below 0 or bigger than 100! Try it again");
                    number = input.nextInt();
                } else {
                    isItOk = true;
                }
            }
            mark[i][j] = number;
        }
    }
```

---

Spoiler 2 : This is a little nicer code, but for beginners, I would recommend the approach of Spoiler 1, because it is always usable. In more complex problems, the Spoiler 2 solution is not always possible.

```
    for (i = 0; i < maxRow; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < maxCol; j++) {
            System.out.print("Please enter ");
            int number = input.nextInt();
            while (number < 0 || number > 100) {
                System.out.println("You shall not insert a value below 0 or bigger than 100! Try it again");
                number = input.nextInt();
            }
            mark[i][j] = number;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number =0;
    System.out.print("Please enter ");
    while(true)
    {
        number = s.nextInt();
        if(number > -1 && number < 101)
            break;
        System.out.println("Marks should be between  0 and 100, Please enter");

    }
```

You also need to validate if input is integer, which can be done through exception handling